# how to give color to a wordpress tab using tabby responsive tabs plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am using tabby responsive tabs plugin to make this tabs but I want when the page load the first tab get orange color and when I click on another tab the color change with my code now it just gives color when I click on it

```
.responsive-tabs__heading,
.responsive-tabs__list__item {
    font-weight: bold!important;
    color: black!important;
    background-color: #E8E8E8!important;
}

.responsive-tabs__heading:focus,
.responsive-tabs__list__item:focus {
    background-color: #ff6720!important;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have a hosted version of this where I can look around I might be able to help you, otherwise we are gonna need a bit more information.

Comment: this is a live version https://www.springinstituut.nl/logistiek-medewerker-mbo-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your live example I noticed they add an active class to the active tab:
`.responsive-tabs__list__item--active`

```
.responsive-tabs__list__item.responsive-tabs__list__item--active {
background-color: red!important;
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

[image]